# Choosing embedded EJB 3.x container to run Java EE 5 app on Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, embedded, jms, ejb, openejb

I am sorry in advance if my question sounds too generic - I am doing all preliminary research myself but nothing substitutes real experience...

My goal is to port a legacy Java EE application (pre-EJB 3.x) to Tomcat with embedded EJB container. My choices currently stand as follows:

- JBoss Embeddable EJB
- Apache OpenEJB
- OW2 Consortium EasyBeans
- anything else?

I am expecting to use JMS (with MDBs), Session beans (stateful and stateless), JPA and I am really excited about using JSF with Seam.

Now, given choices above, are there any advantages in using one or another embedded EJB provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are results of my own homework - hopefully someone finds this analysis of embedded EJB providers helpful on deciding if and which container to use.

I went with Apache OpenEJB since it offers rich set of features, partially supports EJB 3.1 and seems as the most active and well rounded-up offering.

As usual, which product should work best for you really depends on your actual requirements, goals, and environment.

**Embedded JBoss**

- *License*: LGPL
- *Java*: JDK 5.0
- *Tomcat integration*: Yes, modification to server.xml
- *Tomcat Versions*: 5.0 and above (?)
- *Deployment to Tomcat*: Embedded war
- *List of features*: JNDI (local), JBoss TS, JBoss Messaging, JCA, JNDI,
  EJB, JPA, local TX
  datasource/connection pool, EJB
  Security JNDI configuration:
  overrides Tomcat's JNDI
  implementation by layering itself on
  top of Tomcat's JNDI instantiation;
  Tomcat JNDI is read-only
- *Deployment types*: JAR only
- *Management support*: No
- *Support*: limited, built on top JBoss Microcontainer that is the core
  of JBoss 5.0, supported option for
  Seam on Tomcat
- *JMS Provider*: same configuration files as JBoss 5.x. JMS is configured
  in hsqldb-persistence-service.xml,
  and this can be adjusted to work with
  other databases
- *XA Connection Pool*: No
- *EJB Timer Services*: No
- *Persistence Providers:*Hibernate
- *Limitations*: no remote JMS; local interfaces only; local-only JBoss
  JNDI implementation
- *Documentation*: limited
- *EJB 3.1*: No

**Apache OpenEJB 3.1**

- *License:*   Apache License
- *Java:*JDK 5.0 or 6.0
- *Tomcat integration*:Yes, modifications to startup shell script
- *Tomcat Versions:*Tomcat 6.x or 5.5
- *Deployment to Tomcat:*war file
- *List of features:*EJB 3.0 and 3.1, JTA, JAX-WS, JMS, J2EE Connectors, JPA, JNDI. OpenEJB uses several other open source frameworks such as OpenJPA to provide JPA and CMP persistence, ActiveMQ for JMS/MDB, and Apache CXF for JAX-WS features.
- *JNDI configuration:*flexible JNDI naming schema
- *Deployment types:*Collapsed EAR (war), JAR
- *Management support:* ActiveMQ JMX mbeans
- *Support:*Community support, mailing lists and forums, EJB container for Apache Geronimo
- *JMS Provider:*ActiveMQ
- *XA Connection Pool:*Yes
- *EJB Timer Services:*Yes
- *Persistence Providers:*OpenJPA, Hibernate
- *Limitations:*OpenEJB uses OpenJPA to provide JPA and CMP persistence, and OpenJPA currently requires a JavaAgent to function properly.
- *Documentation:*limited but better than others
- *EJB 3.1:*partial

**EasyBeans**

- *License:*LGPL
- *Java:*JDK 5.0 or 6.0
- *Tomcat integration*: Yes
- *Tomcat Versions:*Tomcat 6.x or 5.5
- *Deployment to Tomcat:*war file
- *List of features:*EJB 3.0, JAX-WS, OSGi support
- *JNDI configuration:*?
- *Deployment types:*JAR
- *Management support:*?
- *Support:*Community support and professional support, mailing list, JIRA, EJB container for JOnAS application server
- *JMS Provider:*?
- *XA Connection Pool:*?
- *EJB Timer Services:*Yes
- *Persistence Providers:*OpenJPA, Hibernate, TopLink, EclipseLink
- *Limitations:*
- *Documentation:*limited
- *EJB 3.1:* No